# MongoDb document update without model classes - dynamic objects

Tags: mongodb, dbobject

I am new to using mongo db - and trying to learn mongo template and db object and see how to do update and insert without writing the model classes for every documents.

I will have a lot documents to update [ multiple collections also].
I will get my input as JSON - and want to write service which can parse the json and do inserts and updates.

Can anyone please point me to some good links which i can read about this ?

Thanks much,

Comment: You are looking for this I think: [MongoDB Java Driver Tutorial](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/).

Comment: thank you -i will check this - i dont really want to write model classes for all entities.. and looking for updating using json, by passing the collection ..

Comment: In such case use the `org.bson.Document` class (you will find this in the API docs from my earlier link); you can parse a JSON string to a `Document` instance and write to the collection.

Comment: thank you - can i use the parsing and do update also ? any samples to share ?

Comment: _"can i use the parsing and do update also ?"_ : You can try the collection's `replace` method. You can also try using the `mongoimport` command-line tool to import JSON documents into MongoDB. There is `--mode` option with values: insert, upsert, delete and merge.

Comment: trying to do in java if possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234700/discussion-between-mmenon-and-prasad).